# moment.js unable to use in backbone template

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, momentjs

I am trying to moment.js function moment().format() inside my backbone template as shown below.

```
<td> 
  <% 
  var x = new Date(start); print(moment().format()) 
  %>
</td>
```

it doesn't work.  It gives an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined

But it works within my view module. For example, if I call in the init function, it logs the moment time value correctly.

```
    initialize : function() {
        /* Listen to our collection for reset event */
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
        console.log("moment", moment().format());
    },
```

what am i missing here..?

PS: I am loading moment.js via require js in my view module.

Comment: The template you are using probably has <% %> as its own syntax.  Which template are you using? You can get moment specific result in your view.js and then pass that result to your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roman says, moment.js is not  in the scope of the template rendered. But, Marionette makes it easy to put it in scope. For that purpose you can use `templateHelpers`. Like this:

```
templateHelpers: {
   moment: moment // <-- this is the reference to the moment in your view
}
```

`templateHelpers` will make its `moment` property available in your template as a variable named `moment`. You don't change a thing in the template itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that because of the require.js, the moment.js is only available to your view only.
You have a few options:

1. Assign it to window (e.g. window.moment = require('moment')), so it will be globally accessible.
2. Don't use it in templates, but rather use logic less templates and do the data manipulation elsewhere.
3. Use handlebars as template engine and add moment as a global helper
4. Use marionette and provide the moment.js using the templateHelpers.

Comment: I am changing my strategy of handling date formatting. Thinking of providing model methods that format the date value, and have them called by the view.

Comment: Having the template access the model breaks encapsulation and unidirectional data flow, that will make maintenance more problematic in the future. I suggest sticking to overriding serializeData and using templateHelpers.